# How to make Multiple PHP checkbox set to checked based on database result?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, mysqli

I wanna edit an info of a checkbox in a page but when I clicked the edit link I want the already selected multiple checkbox from the database to be set as checked. But the result I get from my code is that only the last selected checkbox is set as checked(ticked) instead of all the selected checkbox.

Here's my code:

```
<td><input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value = "Badminton" <?php if($interest == 'Badminton') echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>/>Badminton</td>
<td><input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value = "Baseball" <?php if($interest == 'Baseball') echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>/>Baseball</td>
<td><input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value = "Basketball" <?php if($interest == 'Basketball') echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>/>Basketball</td>
<td><input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value = "Cricket" <?php if($interest == 'Cricket') echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>/>Cricket</td>
<td><input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value = "Football" <?php if($interest == 'Football') echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>/>Football</td>
```

and heres my sql code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM interest where username = '$username'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $interest = $row['interest_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to make the creation of the `<td`s happen within the while loop, so that you can use the current value of `$interest` at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: What wrong you are doing is that every time you are overriding the `$interest`.
You need to implement some logic to save all values in an array and then in your PHP code put check accordingly whether the value exists or not. 
Edit: See the answer of @devpro

Comment: @ADyson I don't think that makes any difference(I have checked after your help).

Comment: Clearly, I'm the exception, not the rule, but I just don't answer questions that begin 'I wanna'

Comment: @JayeshDhandha: thank you for recommendation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your values in to an array then you can use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check:

```
<?php
$interest = array(); // initializing  
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $interest[] = $row['interest_name']; // store in an array
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<td>
     <input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value = "Badminton" <?=(in_array('Badminton',$interest) ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?> />Badminton
</td>
```

**Side Note:** Change other checkbox as same above with different values which you have.

Comment: @SangTonsing: `print_r($interest)` check what r u getting in this and share

Comment: I have tried but still none is selected. Anyway @pr1nc3 gave the right one. But really appreciate for your help@devpro.Thank You

Comment: both code same actually i was using `'checked=""'` which was not working in your code so you need to change `'checked=""'` with `'checked="checked"'` if want to use ternary operator @SangTonsing

Comment: Yeah good to know that too, Thank you so much for your help @devpro

Comment: can you help me for the next step on how to update the value of that updated checkbox in a database @devpro

Comment: @SangTonsing: same as u are doing in INSERT record by using `$_POST['checkbox']` ,here u will use update query

Comment: @SangTonsing: or u can remove old record and insert new entry

Comment: I did it like before by inserting it but it seems theres a problem because whenever I untick or tick(checked) another option it displays only the last value of the checked checkbox in database/html page, the nth number of checkbox that I checked the nth number of times the value I get only for the last checkbox checked. And I cant insert again because I want the original value to be replaced and moreover I cant have two values of the same name.@devpro

Comment: @SangTonsing: please create an another questioni on stackoverflow and share

Answer (score 4):

First of all your if you want to use all the values coming from your query you need to store them in an array something like:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $interest[] = $row['interest_name'];
}
```

Now when it comes to your html you can go like:

```
<td><input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox[]" value = "Football" <?php if(in_array('Football',$interest)) echo "checked = 'checked'"; ?>/>Football</td>
```

Just the first example, you should do it in all of them.

Comment: can you help me for the next step @pr1nc3 on how to update that updated checkbox in database